# Why is Stream.distinct not distinct?

Tags: scala, stream, distinct-values

I'm trying the following code and am surprised to find duplicates. I thought that `Stream.distinct` would only return distinct values. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.util.Random.shuffle

object DistinctStreamTest {
   def rand(): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(shuffle(1 to 1000).head, rand()).distinct

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val usedNumbers = mutable.HashSet.empty[String]
      (0 to 100).foreach(i => {
         val newNumber = rand().take(1).mkString
         if (usedNumbers.contains(newNumber)) {
            println(s"Found duplicates: $newNumber after $i iterations")
         }
         usedNumbers += newNumber
      })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting duplicates is that you've defined `rand()` as a `def`. That means that every invocation creates a new and different `Stream[Int]`. You're only taking the 1st element from each new `Stream` but the likelihood of repetition is pretty high.

You could fix it by making `rand` a `val` instead, but you've defined it recursively and so trying to access anything after the head will cause an infinite recursion.

The proper way to get a random sequence of distinct values:

```
val sq :Seq[Int] = util.Random.shuffle(1 to 1000)
```

Then to access the values you might:

```
(0 to 100).foreach(i => {
  val newNumber = sq(i).toString()
  ... //etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `rand()` to be an infinitely recursive `Stream`; since it cannot be materialized, it cannot be distinctified.

```
scala> def rand(): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(shuffle(1 to 1000).head, rand()).distinct
rand: ()Stream[Int]

scala> rand().toList.length
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:61)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike.copyToArray(IterableLike.scala:252)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike.copyToArray$(IterableLike.scala:247)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.copyToArray(Iterable.scala:54)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:99)
  at scala.util.Random.shuffle(Random.scala:108)
```

`Stream`s are lazy, so taking things from them is fine without blowing the stack.

Comment: So you can’t make infinite streams distinct?

Comment: You can't make recursive streams distinct.

Comment: @uzilan You could define rand, then do `rand.distinct`. Beware: this will still go into an infinite loop if you try to read past 1000 elements.